# Как расставить знаки препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос однажды, но, к сожалению, так и не разобрался: когда можно опускать кавычки, и какой знак ставится после перечисления. Вот само предложение:

**Ребенок, в лексиконе которого отсутствуют слова: спасибо, пожалуйста и извините, я думаю, заслуживает по крайней мере порицания.**

"Спасибо", "пожалуйста", "извините" не надо брать в кавычки? И после "извините" просто запятая?

Answer (score 1):

(1) По поводу кавычек - вопрос спорный (см. [Слово (")машина(") - нужны ли здесь кавычки?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433467/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8)).

(2) Для постановки двоеточия нет причин.
Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*Обратите внимание на название комплексов -везде присутствуют слова «танец» и «игры»*. [Мьянмарские мечи (2003) // «Боевое искусство планеты», 2003.12.08]

*Еще в ее лексиконе есть слова «rock'n'roll», «fun», «party» и «love».* [Мария Петрова, Яна Зубцова. Анна Суи: жизнь  стиле буги (2002)

(3) "Я думаю" - вводные слова, они выделяются запятыми.

**Ребенок, в лексиконе которого отсутствуют слова "спасибо", "пожалуйста" и "извините", я думаю, заслуживает по крайней мере порицания.**

Comment: Скажите, а почему в данном предложении нельзя считать "слова" обобщающим словом (и по этой причине поставить двоеточие)?

Comment: На мой взгляд, "слова" слишком общее понятие, чтобы служить обобщающим словом для  "спасибо", "пожалуйста" и "извините".

Comment: Розенталь называет это "общим приложением, не выступающим в роли обобщающего слова".

Comment: Другое дело, если было бы написано "отсутствуют следующие слова:".

Comment: А если такой вариант. В этом перечне отсутствуют слова: ..... Разве я не могу здесь поставить двоеточие перед перечислением?

Comment: Можно, если это уточнение, то есть вы подразумеваете "отсутствуют слова, а именно ... " Но это другой оттенок смысла.