# Нужны ли кавычки в таких сочетаниях, как слово машина, слово пальто и др.?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот предложение с учебного сайта: **Сколько слогов в слове машина?**

**Кавычек нет, а нужны ли они, какую функцию выполняют?** И главное - есть ли правило у Розенталя или Лопатина, где можно получить ответ на этот вопрос?

Надо сказать, что  пользователи решают эту проблему самостоятельно, например: слово пальто, слово "пальто", слово Пальто.

Comment: Хотя вопрос остался неясным, всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кавычки здесь не нужны, так же как в сочетаниях: *буква А*, предложение *Я пошёл* *в магазин*. Вы правы, это приложение, где сочетаются родовое и видовое понятия. Но очень многие их ставят; каюсь, я тоже этим грешу. А вот почему? Может быть, Зализняк нам поможет понять. У него есть статья "Значение кавычек".

[СЕМАНТИКА КАВЫЧЕК | philology.ru](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/zaliznyak_anna-07.htm)

Кавычки могут выполнять следующие функции:

1. Передача прямой речи.
2. Слово или словосочетание является названием литературных произведений, газет, журналов, предприятий, пароходов и т.п. [Правила 1956].
3. *Слово или выражение употреблено в метаязыковой функции, т.е. для указания именно на это слово или выражение, а не на обозначаемый им предмет или понятие.*
4. Отсылка к предтексту (т.е. к предшествующему употреблению данного слова или выражения в том же тексте тем же автором).
5. Показатель «чужого слова».
6. Показатель «своего смысла».

Вот, видимо, мы подсознательно хотим выделить само слово, привлечь внимание к нему, т.е. используем метаязыковую функцию (3 пункт).

Пишущий  хочет выделить (с помощью кавычек) данное слово или выражение (по разным причинам), сделать так, чтобы внимание читающего на нем задержалось. В этой функции используются также: **в рукописном тексте — подчеркивание, в печатном — курсив, полужирный, разрядка или написание прописными буквами** (т. е. любое средство выделения).

Я заостряю внимание на слове *также*, значит, это всё-таки возможно? Получается, что по правилам кавычки не нужны (по правилам обособления приложений), но чтобы было понятно, какое именно слово, а лень выделять курсивом, можно выделить и с помощью кавычек. В учебных текстах, конечно, надо писать по правилам, т. е. без кавычек.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, за ответ.  Мне кажется, что кавычки не нужно применять, но как-то выделять надо.  Я посмотрела пару учебников, Розенталя в том числе, в них везде применяется выделение курсивом, например: слово *нет*, фразеологизм *как в воду канул*.

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 1):

a. Есть ли правило у Розенталя или Лопатина? Хотите знать руководствовались ли они правилами, употребляя сочетание *[слово] [слово]*? Правила для словарных статей одни: основное слово выделяется прямым полужирным или прямым курсивом полужирным.

б. В других текстах правила не предписывают, но рекомендуют (наряду с курсивом и иной жирностью шрифта) р а з р я д к у, КАПИТЕЛЬ или цвет: [Выделяйте правильно! | i-type.ru](http://www.i-type.ru/select2.html)

Comment: Не совсем Вас поняла, меня интересует не выделение шрифтом, а именно кавычки. У Розенталя есть тема, связанная с употреблением кавычек http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/54.htm   Но там не рассматривается этот вариант:  слово (= синтаксическая единица) + конкретное слово.

Comment: Здесь (на сайте) кавычками часто пользуются по причине недоработанности перехода с сохранением графики с общевопросной страницы на конкретную.

Comment: PS/ Не рассматривается и правильно, потому что их не используют «в приличных домах».

Comment: Всё очень интересно, но всё-таки скажите, нужны ли кавычки для "машина"  в этом предложении:  Сколько слогов в слове машина?

Comment: Если объясните, в какой степени  кавычки влияют на количество слогов, я задумаюсь над вторым вопросом. А пока: Слово СЛОВО или слово с л о в о. В комментарии нет иной возможности выделения основного слова.

Comment: В каких случаях нужны кавычки?
В современном русском языке кавычки выполняют следующие функции:
Выделение безабзацной прямой речи и цитат.
Выделение условных (собственных) наименований.
Выделение слов, которые употребляются в необычном, ироническом, особом значении. ========== http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1

Comment: Тогда другое предложение: (1) Почему не склоняется слово метро? (2) Почему не склоняется слово "метро"? Какой вариант правильный?

Comment: ЛЮБОЕ слово может стоять вторым в сочетании, указанном в ответе, даже слово СЛОВО. Чем слово МЕТРО лучше или хуже иных? Вопрос риторический, отвечать не надо.

Answer (score 1):

"Сколько слогов в слове машина?" Кто ответит, здесь "машина" в обычном или необычном значении? Ведь слово "машина" - не вид транспорта, а лексическая единица. По-моему, четких правил нет, и нужно руководствоваться здравым смыслом. Если кавычки нужны для правильного понимания текста - ставьте их. Можете обойтись без кавычек - не ставьте.

Comment: Да  сама машина тут ни при чем, я привела этот пример, так как он взят из учебного сайта, и люди там как-то отвечают за правильность письма. Это ОБЩИЙ ВОПРОС: нужны кавычки в таких сочетаниях или нет. По грамматике оно похоже на род+вид (например, птица воробей),  но это сочетание особое по смыслу. Или если мы имеем однородный ряд, нужны ли кавычки вообще,  нужны ли для каждого слова? А здравый смысл у всех разный, можно написать: слово Пальто, если четких правил нет. Я, к примеру, пишу кавычки, но у меня нет уверенности, что это правильно.

Comment: Похоже на сочетания со словом термин:  термин реакция или термин "реакция"? Похоже, для терминов тоже нет единого правила.