# Нужны ли кавычки для буквы?

Tags: пунктуация

Верно писать: «Пишется через "***и***"» или «Пишется через ***и***»? 
В этом предложении ***и*** надо брать в кавычки?

Comment: Похожая тема обсуждалась здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433467/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80/433469#433469

Answer (score -2):

Надо, обязательно надо, именно в кавычках!