# Знак после "в переводе"

Tags: пунктуация

**Сейчас мы прослушаем трек Lost In Space, в переводе "Затерянный в космосе".**
Нужно ли двоеточие? Может быть, тире? Как вообще подобные тексты оформлять? В Нацкорпусе вариантов много, вот, например, из одного текста два случая:

> ...Хотя слово "мемуар" в переводе с французского означает "память".

> ― А что такое Сатеник?
> ― В переводе означает янтарь.

Почему во втором примере нет двоеточия, понятно: его заменяет слово "означает". Но почему нет кавычек?

А вот пример с тире и без кавычек:

> Дьякон в переводе с греческого ― служитель.

В общем, я несколько запутался.

Comment: Можно в скобки отправить, убрав лишнее «в переводе».

Comment: @shampar можно-то можно, но интересно разобраться в моём варианте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Тема 1. О кавычках и курсиве**

Эта тема уже обсуждалась на форуме, где из всего сказанного я поняла следующее. Выделение кавычками (курсивом) **не регламентируется** специальными правилами.  Однако Розенталь и Грамота.ру считают выделение второй части сочетания желательным, но при этом в научной и учебной литературе предпочитают **курсив, а не кавычки**, например: **слово *нет*.**

Кавычки (курсив) имеют более широкие функции по сравнению с тем, что перечислено в учебниках. В частности важна **разделительная роль** кавычек, определяющих границы.

К примеру, рассмотрим видовые сочетания: **гора Казбек** – здесь границы определены прописной буквой; **слово *нет*** – для двух нарицательных существительных границы желательно обозначить; фразеологизм ***браться за ум***  –  для сочетаний из нескольких слов  границы нужно обозначать обязательно.

**Тема 2. О соответствии слов в разных языках**

В этой теме просматриваются **различные связи**, а именно:  (1) между словом и понятием, (2) между словами в разных языках, отнесенных к одному понятию.

Также есть два глагола – *значить и обозначать*,  причем они оба управляют В.п.  В первом значении они совпадают, хотя глагол «обозначать» имеет более широкое применение, и он ближе к понятию, чем к слову.

Все это приводит **к разному оформлению текста**, причем записи носят довольно **условный характер,** то есть они кажутся неточными по смыслу.

(1) *Хотя слово "мемуар" в переводе с французского означает "память".* Русское слово *мемуар* соответствует французскому слову  mémoire, что  означает (понятие) память.

(2))*― А что такое Сатеник? ― В переводе означает янтарь.* Русское слово *Сатеник* соответствует армянскому слову  Սաթենիկ, что  означает (понятие) янтарь.

Становится понятной **необходимость такой** условности.  Разные же  записи можно объяснить разной **лексикой или  разными стилями**, то есть автор определяет сам необходимость разделительной функции кавычек/курсива (иногда они нужны, а иногда текст и так понятен).

**Тема 3. О знаках (тире, запятая, нет знака)**

Этот вопрос решается по общим правилам письма, с учетом грамматики и структуры предложения.

*Сейчас мы прослушаем трек Lost In Space, в переводе "Затерянный в космосе".*

Здесь присоединительная конструкция, обособленная запятой. Оборот неполный, но его содержание вполне ясное и включает составное имя собственное, заключенное в кавычки.

*Дьякон в переводе с греческого ― служитель.*

Здесь пропущенный глагол одновременно выполняет разделительную функцию кавычек. Также можно считать, что это тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в простом предложении.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433467/Нужны-ли-кавычки-в-таких-сочетаниях-как-слово-машина-слово-пальто-и-др](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433467/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80)

**Вопрос № 280241.** Почему вы не берёте слова, представленные в качестве примера в тексте, в кавычки? Согласно элементарной логике, это было бы правильно…
Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Мы обычно используем курсив. Так уж повелось, что в словарях и справочниках примеры обычно выделяют курсивом, мы следуем этой традиции.

**ОЗНАЧАТЬ**, нсв. что. 1. Иметь тот или иной смысл, значение (о словах, знаках, жестах). Что означает ваше молчание? Многоточие означает пропуск текста.

**ЗНАЧИТЬ**, нсв. 1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать (о словах, знаках, жестах и т. п.). Имя Виктор значит победитель. Кивок головы значит согласие. Изумлённый взгляд слушателя значил, что он не согласен.

Comment: Спасибо, исчерпывающе)