# Нужны ли в данном случае кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, кавычки, оформление-текста

*Я настолько одинок, что мне не хватит слова "столь".*

Правильно? Если нет, то как правильно написать это предложение?

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос уже задавали, см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433467/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80).

В вашем случае **кавычки уместны**, их функция такова.

> 3. *Слово или выражение употреблено в метаязыковой функции, т. е. для указания именно на это слово или выражение, а не на обозначаемый им предмет или понятие.*

В "Нацкорпусе" можно найти множество аналогичных примеров, приведу лишь несколько.

*Но тогда зачем подменять русское **слово «сведения»** иностранным ― **«информация»**?* [Интерпретации и смысл понятия «информация» // «Информационные технологии», 2004]

*Теперь оба президента неспешно расставляют акценты, не забывая вновь употреблять **слово «успех»** как главный результат своего общения.* [Екатерина Григорьева. Расстановка акцентов. Владимир Путин поделился впечатлениями о Джордже Буше // «Известия», 2001.06.19]

*Одно **слово "политика"** вызывало у них тошноту.* [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

*Вот за **слово "капитализм"**, которое я не нашёлся сразу заменить **"толстосумством"**, и за **слово** **"шпионить"**, которое я сгоряча поленился заменить **словом** **"доглядать"**, ― я и поставил себе две палочки.* [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

*Сколько раз в жизни мне приходилось слышать **слово "интеллигент"** по своему адресу.* [М. А. Булгаков. Записки покойника (Театральный роман) (1936-1937)]

Comment: Вам ясен смысл предложения?  Тогда не очень понятна  метаязыковая функция выделенного кавычками слова именно в этом предложении. Вообще говоря, обычно слово выделяется курсивом или кавычками во всех случаях (например, у Розенталя: слово нет).  Хотелось бы, чтобы вы указали ссылки на Розенталя, ПАС или Грамоту.ру, то есть на существующую практику, а не на теорию письма у Зализняка.